# What does the "this" pointer points to inside a constructor in C++?

Tags: c++, pointers

In C++ the "this" pointer points to the invoking object. However, when we call a constructor with a parameter, what does the "this" pointer point to?

For example, the following line calls the constructor:

```
TestManager myTest(device_name);
```

If I put a breakpoint inside the constructor function:

```
TestManager::TestManager(string device_name)
{
// bunch of code    
}
```

What should I expect the "this" pointer pointing to?

The reason I am asking this question is that in my code, the "this" pointer is pointing to another object in my code that is not being called or used anywhere.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `this` always points to the object. Period. Even in constructors and destructors.

Comment: @MooingDuck yes, it is supposed to point to the invoking object. But in this case, what is the invoking object? We are creating an object.

Comment: The memory for the object has already been allocated, it's just not fully initialized (that's the job of the constructor), the `this` pointer simply points to the memory that has been allocated.

Comment: @MrAliB No, it doesn't point to the *invoking* object. It points to the object that is being constructed. In this case, `this` points to `myTest`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`this` always points to the object. In the case of constructors or destructors, that means the object being constructed or destructed.

> The reason I am asking this question is that in my code, the "this" pointer is pointing to another object in my code that is not being called or used anywhere.

Assuming your code is written somewhat sensibly, the object's only used after its construction has finished, so it makes sense that during the constructor, you haven't seen that particular value elsewhere yet.

Answer (score 1):

'This' is pointing to an object that you are using currently. If you are writing methods, constructor, destructor, you can use 'this'. If you are writing friend functions, or static functions, you can't use 'this'.

Answer (score 0):

`this` points to the instance of the current object being initialized. Once you reached the constructor, the necessary space for the object instance is already allocated and `this` points to it.

Just be careful when subclassing, and calling virtual/overriden methods from within a constructor:

Example:

```
class A {
  A() {
    this->work();
  }

  virtual void work() {
    // ...
  }
};

class B : public A {
  B() {
    // ...
  }

  void work() override {
    // use some private members of B
  }
};
```

In this case, working with private members from `A` from within `A`'s constructor is fine. But since derived classes' members are initialized (and allocated!) after the base class, the private members of `B` are invalid until you reached `B`'s constructor. So your program will most probably crash if you run into this situation.

Other than that, I cannot think of any problems with using `this` in the constructor of `A`.